# blank input:hover fields within the list items BG color to be set by jQuery

Tags: jquery

My website looks bad because the blank input:hover fields within the list:hover items have the same BG as the non-blank ones. There is no css fix for altering blank input fields, AFAIK. I want use jQuery to find all the blank list item within the list items and change the :hover attribute BG to, say.. pink. Can you help with this? No one seems to be too close in getting this. Yes, he's showed us http://verlager.com/super-dev.com and how the empty list/input items have an annoying brown BG on hover. Can we get this? It may be rather difficult.

HTML:

```
<li class="ui-state-default" id = "L1"><input type="text" name = "N1" id = "I1" disabled /></li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id = "L2"><input type="text" name = "N2" id = "I2" disabled /></li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id = "L3"><input type="text" name = "N3" id = "I3" disabled /></li>
```

CSS:

```
#sortable li:hover {background-color: #4B5A72; color: #DFFEFF;}
#sortable li:hover > input {text-align:left}

#sortable {list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin:0 auto; margin-top:-1rem; display:table; }
#sortable li {width: 21rem !important; padding:0.25rem 0.5rem; background:inherit; float:left; border-radius:0px;}
#sortable li input {width:19rem !important; text-shadow:none !important; padding:0.35rem; color:inherit; height:2.0rem; line-height:2.0rem; background:#CCC59A; font-size: 1.5rem;  letter-spacing:1px !important; border:none; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; font-weight:bold !important; cursor:text;}
#sortable li input:focus {color:black !important; background:#FFFADA; text-align:center; text-shadow:none; }
#sortable li:focus {padding:0rem !important;}

.pink: {background-color: transparent;}
.pink:hover {background-color: transparent;}
```

Comment: what do you mean by blank input? Is it mean disable input?

Comment: The input is blank. Some are blank, some have player's names and ratings. The blank ones are confusing because user can hover over them and BG changes.

Comment: See http://verlager.com/super-dev.php and move mouse over the center area. It looks terrible and amateurish.

Comment: We need this because the non-blank names boxes can be moved with jquery ui sortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by loading the css file and removing all !important css tags. Don't ask me how it worked. I just know it is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you need to loop through the input boxes and check if the value is empty. If so, assign the class `pink` to it, otherwise, don't.

```js
$('li').hover(function() {
  var input = $(this).find('input[type=text]');
  input.toggleClass('pink', input.val().trim().length === 0);
}, function() {
  var input = $(this).find('input[type=text]');
  input.removeClass('pink');
})
```

```css
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L1"><input type="text" name="N1" id="I1" disabled value="abc" /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L2"><input type="text" name="N2" id="I2" disabled /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L3"><input type="text" name="N3" id="I3" disabled /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Trouble is it's a :hover not a BG color change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseover` and `mouseleave` or simply use `hover` like the followings.

Note that `disabled` input wouldn't be triggered.

Edit: Since the mouse event will not get fired on the disabled field, you can replace `input` with `.ui-state-default` to trigger the event.

```js
$('.ui-state-default').mouseover(function() {
  var $input = $(this).find('input')
  if ($input.val().length == 0) {
    $input.css('background', 'pink')
  }
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find('input').css('background', '')
})
```

```css
#sortable li:hover {
  background-color: #4B5A72;
  color: #DFFEFF;
}

#sortable li:hover>input {
  text-align: left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L1"><input type="text" name="N1" id="I1" disabled value="not empty" /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L2"><input type="text" name="N2" id="I2" disabled /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L3"><input type="text" name="N3" id="I3" disabled /></li>
</div>
```

Or

```js
$('.ui-state-default').hover(function() {
  var $input = $(this).find('input')
  if ($input.val().length == 0) {
    $input.css('background', 'pink')
  }
}, function() {
  $(this).find('input').css('background', '')
})
```

```css
#sortable li:hover {
  background-color: #4B5A72;
  color: #DFFEFF;
}

#sortable li:hover>input {
  text-align: left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L1"><input type="text" name="N1" id="I1" disabled value="not empty" /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L2"><input type="text" name="N2" id="I2" disabled /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L3"><input type="text" name="N3" id="I3" disabled /></li>
</div>
```

Comment: these list and input items are all disabled.

Comment: @verlager As per your comment, I updated the snippet.

Comment: see http://verlager.com/super-dev.php view source line 451. There is your code. Now look at page and move mouse over center of page. All hovers have a green BG. I want it transparent!

Comment: You didn't provide enough CSS and HTML to your question, please update your post.

Comment: I have added the requested CSS.

Comment: If you delete the codes I provided, the same issue would still there, right? And there are a lot of details you didn't mention such as `style` of the `li`, the class `.automplete-2` which has `background: inherit !important;`. In this situation, I can't provide any help for that since my codes didn't do anything to the problem you mentioned in your comments.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your efforts. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val().length === 0){
        $(this).css('background', 'pink');
        } else {
        $(this).css('background', '');
        }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L1"><input type="text" name="N1" id="I1" disabled value="abc" /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L2"><input type="text" name="N2" id="I2" disabled /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L3"><input type="text" name="N3" id="I3" disabled /></li>
</ul>
```